# Multiple .live() bound to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nice tooltip script. Scrip puts element's title attribute into tooltip div. Tooltip follows mouse arrow via mousemove, removes div after mouseout and puts element's title back. It works perfect on static pages, but i have some troubles with ajax.

http://jsfiddle.net/b5LRK/3/

And i'm tryin to apply .live() to this script. Something like this:

```
$('[title]').live({
   mouseover: function(e) {
    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

    $('body').append('<div id="tooltip">' + tip + '<div class="tipArrow"></div></div>');

    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 25);
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 15);

}, mousemove: function(e) {

    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 25);
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 15);

}, mouseout: function() {

    $(this).attr('title', $('#tooltip').text());
    $('body').children('div#tooltip').remove();

}});
```

And it's not working! What's the problem?

Comment: maybe because its `live`, when you remove the `title` attribute, the `mouseout` handler is no longer registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, the problem is with the selector - `live()` can't work with selector like **[title]** - it can "listen" to class or element ID selectors though.

[Here is fiddle proving it](http://jsfiddle.net/b5LRK/8/), I just changed `$('[title]')` to `$('.mydiv')`.

So just add a class to the contents you're loading and it should work fine as you can "listen" to this class and `.live()` can know when new elements with such class are added then attach the events.

If you can't control the AJAX contents, you can also apply a class on the fly on all the elements having `title`, for example:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    $("#Panel").append("<div title='hello world'></div>");
    $("#Panel [title]").attr("class", "mydiv");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5LRK/9/).

Comment: kudos. i'm too slow. check out the [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5LRK/10/) though. I stored the title in another attribute, and registered the mouseout to elements that has the `data-title` attribute.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky your fiddle is not working at all, at least for me in Chrome. The tooltip is not "moving" along with the mouse as it should.

Comment: oh, forgot to move the `mousemove` to the [data-title] also. http://jsfiddle.net/b5LRK/11/ . btw, If you don't want to use the browser's title feature, don't use it. store the title you want in a `data-title` attribute or something

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky nice - but isn't `data-something` part of HTML5 though?

Comment: html5 made the data-* formal, but you can use whatever attribute you want. call it `tooltip-title`. I don't think there's a browser who'll complain about it.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a`}` in the end of the `live` function:

```
$('[title]').live({
   mouseover: function(e) {
    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');    
    $('body').append('<div id="tooltip">' + tip + '<div class="tipArrow"></div></div>');

}, mousemove: function(e) {

    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 25);
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 15);

}, mouseout: function() {

    $(this).attr('title', $('#tooltip').text());
    $('body').children('div#tooltip').remove();

}}/*<=that "}" was missing...*/);
```

Comment: @Toon. _not working properly_ what exactly? Please give a **JSFiddle** to work with.

Comment: Tooltip shows. That's all. Seems mousemove and mouseout are not working.

Comment: Yeah, because it's original script without .live()

Comment: @Toon. embaressing... will take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[title]').on("mouseover", function(e) {

    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

    $('body').append('<div id="tooltip">' + tip + '<div class="tipArrow"></div></div>');

    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 25);
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 15);

}).on("mousemove",function(e) {

    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 25);
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 15);

}).on("mouseout",function() {

    $(this).attr('title', $('#tooltip').text());
    $('body').children('div#tooltip').remove();
});
```

with version 1.7 there is new function for live, called on, might help

http://jsfiddle.net/gKsSz/1/